# View Model loading previously searched data(through retrofit call) instead of newly searched

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, android-livedata

I am bit confused how I can send the new query to retrofit call through the view model.
My Activity is as follows:

```
    public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    Button filter_button;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText currentSearch;
    ImageButton imageButton;
    List<Hits> mHits = new ArrayList<>();
    String category;
    String order;
    String query;
    String editor_choice;
    String type;
    ViewModel model;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        filter_button = findViewById(R.id.button_filter);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton_search);
        currentSearch = findViewById(R.id.et_currentsearch);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);


        // getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        category = intent.getStringExtra("category");
        order = intent.getStringExtra("order");
        query = intent.getStringExtra("searchQuery");
        editor_choice = intent.getStringExtra("editor");
        type = intent.getStringExtra("type");
        currentSearch.setText(query);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mHits);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getApplication()
                , category, type, editor_choice, order, query)).get(ViewModel.class);
        model.getList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Hits>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Hits> hits) {
                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(SearchActivity.this, hits);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newSearch();
            }
        });

        filter_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("query", currentSearch.getText().toString().trim());
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the method i am using :

```
    void newSearch() {
        String newSearch = currentSearch.getText().toString();
        Log.d("___", "new Search : " + newSearch);
        ViewModel model1 = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getApplication()
                , category, "photo", "false", "popular", newSearch)).get(ViewModel.class);
        model1.getList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Hits>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Hits> hits) {
                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(SearchActivity.this, hits);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });


    }

}
```

The newSearch in Log is showing the required query but the recyler view is still showing the previously fetched.

My ViewModelFactory Class :

```
public class MyViewModelFactory extends 
ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory {


private Application context;
private String category;
private String image_type;
private String editor_choice;
private String orderBy;
private String query;
public MyViewModelFactory(@NonNull Application application,String category, String image_type,
                          String editor, String orderBy, String  query) {
    super(application);
    this.category = category;
    this.image_type = image_type;
    this.editor_choice = editor;
    this.orderBy = orderBy;
    this.query = query;
    this.context=application;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    return (T) new com.example.picsearch.ViewModel(context,category,image_type
                        ,editor_choice,orderBy,query);
}
```

}

I am new in programming please tell me how I can use the currentSearch text as query for the new Retrofit call.

Comment: You are again adding a new observer in the newSearch Function, observers are meant to attach once and Observing the changes,

Comment: You must change the way you are using ViewModel approach

Comment: Ok i got the point but how to solve the problem i tried removing the observer from the newSearch function but nothing happened

Comment: you are passing the arguments in the constructor, it should be on the getList(), and create view model object only one time and use it again and again

Comment: You have attached the observer already when you try to get the new result just call the function which will provide you the data, and you observer will automatically called

Comment: thank you very much,now i understand what i was doing wrong instead of observing **model.getList()** directly I start observing a new variable which is of type **LiveData<List<>>** and calling **model.getlLst()** function on this variable.Prolem Solved.

Comment: please answer your own question, so others will know